# how to solve $x(e^{-{1\over x}}-1)=$ constant

Tags: exponential-function

As mentionned in the title, how to solve analytically the equation

$x \cdot \left(e^{-\frac{c_1}{x}}-1\right)=c_2$ where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are known constants.

I can easily find a solution numerically, but i would like to validate it analytically.

Comment: Analytically solving an equation to validate the solution should not be done. You should simply plug the value back in and see if the equation is approximately true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x=\dfrac1{at+b}$. Then

$$e^{-{c_1\over x}}=\frac{c_2}x+1$$

becomes

$$e^{-c_1(at+b)}=c_2(at+b)+1,$$

$$e^{-c_1at}e^{-c_1b}=c_2at+c_2b+1.$$

We choose $a=\dfrac1{c_1}$ and $b=-\dfrac1{c_2}$ and the equation simplifies to

$$e^{-t}e^{-c_1b}=c_2at,$$

$$\frac1{c_2a}e^{-c_1b}=te^t,$$ i.e.

$$\frac{c_1}{c_2}e^{c_1/c_2}=te^t.$$

Finally,

$$x=\frac{c_1c_2}{c_2W\left(\frac{c_1}{c_2}e^{c_1/c_2}\right)-c_1},$$ where $W$ denotes the Lambert function. You can't find a simpler form.

Comment: I fixed an error in the computation of $b$. Now the result is fully complaint with Wolfram.

Answer (score 2):

According to Wolfram Alpha the result is

$$x = \frac{c_1c_2}{ {-c_1 + c_2 \cdot W\left({c_1 e^{{c_1 \over c_2}}\over c_2}\right)}}$$

with $W$ being the product logarithm function, which cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions.

Answer (score 1):

This type of equations does not have analytic solution. You can use Taylor formula to estimate it.

Comment: Can you show how ? In my opinion, this is a tremendous task.

Comment: @Yves Daoust : Taylor's formula gives you polynomial approximation of the function and you can estimate the error by the error term.

Answer (score 1):

The analytic solution of the equation is shown below :

[image]